# 2 transactions in 1 block. Anty drainer erc20

Tags: blockchain, payable

I have 2 wallets: on the first - eth, on the second - erc20 tokens.

I need to put 2 transactions in one block:

1. sending eth for gas from wallet 1 to wallet 2.
2. sending erc20 tokens to another wallet.

The problem is that there is a drainer on wallet 2.

How can i do this?
I'm willing to pay for your nodejs code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While [Talha's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/148422/27270) is correct with regards to how blockchains work and transactions are generally submitted, there are still ways to accomplish your goals.

As a bit of an introduction, in order to have better guarantees on rescuing the funds from the compromised wallet, you're really looking for 2 things. You've touched on one - atomicity, meaning that the 2 transactions should be executed as one (atomic) unit, and a malicious party shouldn't be able to stick a transaction in the middle. The other is that you don't want the txs broadcast in the mempool before they're included in a block. The reason for this is that some hackers do not bother searching for all of the assets a compromised address holds. Instead, they simply wait for the compromised party to try transferring them out, and then the hacker simply copies their transaction (at a higher gas price) from the mempool, just sending those tokens to themselves. If the hacker sees txs for the compromised wallet, even if the txs are executed atomically, the hacker may still be able to frontrun them with their own funds, sweeping the tokens before the first rescue transaction fires.

On Ethereum mainnet, [Flashbots](https://www.flashbots.net/) runs a service that provides bundles of transactions to validators to be executed atomically. These transactions are not broadcast publicly beforehand, so they will not be known to the drainer until they are executed, and are also executed together, so there isn't room for a sweeper transaction between steps 1 and 2. You can do this yourself by [assembling a bundle](https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/advanced/rpc-endpoint#eth_sendbundle) of transactions, or can find the `whitehat-token-rescue` channel on their Discord server (links to the server are in their docs). Note that whitehats often charge a fee for performing this service.

There are also other parties that will perform whitehat sweeps on demand, both with them and with anyone you find on Flashbots, make sure to validate the reputation of whoever will be performing the sweep for you in order to do your due diligence that they won't steal the funds themselves.

Note that Flashbots is only on Ethereum as of this writing (Nov 2023). On other chains things can get significantly more complicated. If you are able to submit transactions directly to a block producer, then they can execute both atomically without the txs being broadcast prior to inclusion. It can be difficult to find these lines of communication, however. As a result, on other chains you may want to start by either looking for whitehat services that operate on that chain, or by looking for validator/mining pools with reasonably consistent block production to see if they offer a private tx or whitehat service.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to send `two transactions` specifically in the same block in the Ethereum blockchain.

`Miners` are responsible for selecting which transactions to include in a block, and they usually prioritize transactions with higher `gas prices` to maximize their profits. So even if you submit two transactions simultaneously, they may be included in `different blocks`.

But there could be a way around it by sending transactions with the same nonce, you can try that but again it is not guaranteed that transactions will be included in same block

Comment: I found an example in the blockchain today.  
These transactions follow each other in the same order and in one block.  
At the same time, I am sure that there was no balance on the wallet from where the erc20 tokens were sent.

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9f7f85f4fbf3436c83ce1d3c66fcf6521a39bb30ea462e58caab4c86f80ac81c
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1b276b2a9bf5bbb51f5ff5cdbe78168dee88f61971bf36862fc8a5efc794043a
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x18887ea6df17a2c05857919130749b352d097cc7b8dc05b3cf6688146b18767d

Comment: I tried to write something like this, but I got an error that the eth balance is not enough to send erc20 tokens.  Do you have any ideas how they could implement this?

Comment: It isn't impossible, but you need a miner collaboration.